# Create Custom Action tab bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-titlebar

I am trying to create a custom tabbar using [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-with-fragment-tabs-tutorial/) for android 2.3.3 and above,but the title bar is disabled(Refer the image attached app deployed on Android 2.3.3 ).

[image]

Also, how do I customize the titlebar. Please guide me for the same.

Comment: you have enough score that you should be aware that questions normally contain questions :-)

Comment: I have made several changes in my code, please can you let me changes in which file has resulted in this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I solved it this way. Created new layout for action bar tab's title and initialized first tab like this:

```
// init first tab indicator
View viewTabMain = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_title_layout, null);
((ImageView) viewTabMain.findViewById(R.id.imgTab)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_1);

// add main tab
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_MAIN).setIndicator(viewTabMain).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
@Override
public View createTabContent(String s) {
View view = new View(getApplicationContext());
return view;
}
}));
```

To other tab (or tabs) use the same. I hope this will help you!